unable to resolve "prop-types" from "node_modules\@expo\vector-icons\build\vendor\react-native-vector-icons\lib\icon-button.js
When updating an Expo project to SDK 51, the app failed to launch with the following error:
unable to resolve "prop-types" from "node_modules\@expo\vector-icons\build\vendor\react-native-vector-icons\lib\icon-button.js

What is the issue with this code and how can I resolve them? Where can I specifically check to find and resolve this issue? Thank you

I had the same issue, all you need to do is run:
npx expo install prop-types

And that should fix your problem

This problem occur because in update of the package when apply:
npx expo install --fix
update the package @expo that works with prop-types this issue have two ways:
Easy Way (Its not correct)

Open file icon-button.js
Delete prop-typs.

the correct way

Install prop-types libs using:
npm install prop-types
enter code here


